# GreenHillsCompiler callgraph

Tags: c, linker, call-graph

in our project we have to use the GreenHillsCompiler Suite MULTI. So everything is configured and running. Reading the compiler manual I found an option for the linker which will generate a callgraph.

I added the option to the linker (elxr) in the makefile with

```
LINK_OPT += -callgraph
```

which generates a file with the extension ".graph" in the output folder. This files just contains plain text.

```
Function    Function Call   Call Count  Percent of Total    Max Displacement    (bits)
#% BEGIN STATIC GRAPH
myFunc  out 0   in  3
  out   0   100%
  in    3   100%
  myFunc2   1   33% 0   2514    0
  .static00012204   1   33% 0   514 0
  .static0001220b   1   33% 0   1300    0
#% END STATIC GRAPH
```

So the question is:  What tool has to be used further?

What we want is an image or a html-document.

Comment: As used in contexts such as this, "call graph" does not imply an image. "Graph" is to be understood in the mathematical sense, and loosely at that.  If you want to create an image representing the data then you're probably on your own.

Comment: I understood that. That's why I ask for a tool that would accept that "mathematical graph" and convert it into an image. Like doxygen etc. Unfortunately graphviz doesn't provide an importer for that format.

Answer (score 0):

That is the graph. It is in text format.

Note that if you want a graphical representation of a function's call graph, from within the MULTI debugger you can right-click a function and select `Browse Other -> Browse Static Calls`.

Comment: Found that tool too - thanks. Thought there would be an option which shows you the whole thing (so the whole content of the .graph-file) and not just one piece.